# ansible uri equivalent of curl command

Tags: curl, ansible, uri, grafana

```
curl 'http://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:3000/api/datasources' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' --data-binary '{"name":"influx","type":"influxdb","url":"http://localhost:8086","access":"proxy","isDefault":true,"database":"collectd_db","user":"admin","password":"admin"}'
```

Not sure how to encode this in the ansible uri module. So far I have got this:

```
- name: next add the database to the grafana
 uri:
  url: "http://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:3000/api/datasources"
  method: POST
  user: admin
  password: admin
    body: '{"name":"influx","type":"influxdb","url":"http://localhost:8086","access":"proxy","isDefault":true,"database":""{{ influxdb_database|default(collectd_db) }}"","user":"admin","password":"admin"}'
  body_format: raw
  # force_basic_auth: yes
```

But it does not work and gives following error:

```
  "msg": "Status code was not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>", 
"redirected": false, 
"status": -1, 
"url": "http://********:********@127.0.0.1:3000/api/datasources"
```

}

Comment: Try removing the `admin:admin@` from the url

Answer (score 3):

1. Try setting `body_format` to `json`.
2. Remove the excess indentation before `body`.
3. Remove excess double-quotes around `"{{ influxdb_database|default(collectd_db) }}"`
4. Remove `admin:admin@` from `url:` value (it's already set through `user` and `password`).

Let us know how you get on after that!

Answer (score 1):

I had to resort to the 'command' module

```
- name: Add graphite datasource
  command: >
    curl 'http://admin:admin@{{ inventory_hostname }}:3000/api/datasources' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' --data-binary '{"name":"Graphite Live","type":"graphite","url":"http://graphiteserver.foo.bar","access":"direct","isDefault":true,"database":"asd"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paste your command into [curlconverter.com/ansible](https://curlconverter.com/ansible/) and it'll convert it to this:

```yaml
-
  name: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/datasources'
  uri:
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/datasources'
    method: POST
    body:
      name: influx
      type: influxdb
      url: 'http://localhost:8086'
      access: proxy
      isDefault: true
      database: collectd_db
      user: admin
      password: admin
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    url_username: admin
    url_password: admin
  register: result
```